# Tortiose SVN Revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I find the list of revisions in my repository, without having to check everything out?  I'm looking for something that was deleted a while back, but I'm not sure when.  I need to get a list of all the revisions, like the Revision Graph, but without having to check everything out.  Did that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click, TortoiseSVN, Repo-browser. You can then check the revision graph and everything else from a browser that connects to the repository and not the file system.

Answer (score 2):

All the svn commands accept repository URLS as arguments so you can work on them w/o checking them out, e.g.:

> svn log http://my.repo.url/something

Comment: Ack, just actually read the question and noticed the TortoiseSVN requirement. In that case, do what David M suggests :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Subversion log. You should be able to check out one folder without recursing into its subdirectories.

If you were doing it from the command line, you could type "svn log 
v http://example.org/repository" to see a list of revisions and files changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check out at least the folder which probably contains the deleted files. Then you can access the history with context-menu.

Comment: Thats the whole problem, I'd have to check out the entire root folder, and it is huge

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and just check everything out, and was able to access a Revision Log from there without having to actually check it all out.

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you have to check out anything.
You basically select TortoiseSVN > Repo-browser from context menu and put the path to the SVN Repository.
Once you've got repository opened, right click on the main root folder and select Show Log.
Should give you a complete history of revisions.